# How do I remove the little red line marking the initial value of the amplitude in my slider?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-widget

I am using a `matplotlib.widgets` slider and it's working perfectly but there is a little red line that marks the initial value of the slider that I would like to remove. I checked the documentation for the `Slider` function and there was a mention of something called a vline or hline which I think is what I'm looking to remove but it doesn't say anywhere how to remove that line. [Here is what I'm referring to.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wf3k9.png)

And here is the code I have for showing the slider:

```
amp_slider = Slider(ax=axamp, label='Amplitude', valmin=0, valmax=10, valinit=init_amplitude, orientation='vertical')
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
amp_slider.hline._linewidth = 0
```

To find it, I just printed the elements of `some_slider.hline.__dict__.keys()`. For a horizontal slider (default), it would be the vline that needs to be adjusted.